# Using findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths to change datasource for ArcSDE geodatabase?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, esri-geodatabase, arcpy

I manage to change my datasouce by right clicking on an mxd file and choosing a different sde database connection file as shown in the following image.
[image: *enter image description here*]

However When I try to do this using arcpy script the datasource it is not changed, but the new mxd is created (having the old datasource)

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\SMALIS\Documents\ArcGIS\pythonSwitchSource.mxd")
mxd.findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths(r"Database Connections\sdeConnection1.sde",r"Database Connections\sdeConnection2.sde")
mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Users\SMALIS\Documents\ArcGIS\pythonSwitchSourceNEW.mxd")
del mxd
```

Can somebody explain me why is that happening?

I use ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.
Oracle 11g

Comment: I had a similar Q http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64064/python-change-sde-data-source-for-mxds-in-specific-folder

You need to use the full path name for your SDE

Answer (score 2):

I have also had issues with this...This [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/32468/permanently-replace-update-server-service-in-each-arcsde-layer-in-mxd) was helpful.  In our case, we have 50+ mxd's we use for web applications, each with a corresponding SDE database.  We just upgraded our SDE and ArcGIS Server so I used the lyr.replaceDataSource to explicitly set the SDE workspace and it seemed to work much better.  It still missed a few, but for some reason I can never get the findAndReplaceWorkspacePaths to work properly

Comment: import arcpy;
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Users\SMALIS\Documents\ArcGIS\pythonSwitchSource.mxd");
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.supports("DATASOURCE"):
            lyr.replaceDataSource("C:\Users\SMALIS\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\DB1.sde", "SDE_WORKSPACE", lyr.datasetName, False) 
mxd.saveACopy(r"C:\Users\SMALIS\Documents\ArcGIS\1.mxd");
del mxd;

Comment: I Tried your suggestion. I seems to replace the datasource and created the new mxd (1.mxd) with the new datasource. However , when I try to show the map, with data coming from the new datasource, ArcMap says that I have to repair the datasource ("!" symbol on the left of the layer in table of content area)

Comment: Hmm, maybe try using the path r"Database Connections\DB1.sde".  This is an alias for the exact same path you are using, but maybe some stuff under the hood will validate it properly.